# How do I play Portal 2 workshop maps?

Tags: steam, portal-2

I've subscribed to several workshop maps in Portal 2, but when I launch the game, I can't find the maps.  I've tried searching on YouTube for answers to this question and all the videos have a menu option for workshop maps, but there's no menu option on my main menu to click on. What do I do now?

Answer (score 6):

First go to the main menu and go on the community test chambers. Then go on either single player or co-op. Use the mouse/controller to scroll to "My Queue" and it should say all the names and maps of the chamber you have got. Happy playing!

Comment: This is now the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

The maps should be saved in:

- Windows XP/Vista/7 32bit

c:\program files\steam\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\maps

- Windows XP/Vista/7 64bit

c:\program files (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\maps

- Mac OS

Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/portal 2/portal2/maps

Then you should be able to find them using either the changelevel command in the console window (eg changelevel mp_coop_map name) or the normal level select chooser in the GUI.

Comment: What if the maps don't appear, huh? SteamApps folder has no "common" subfolder. What to do now?

Comment: No common subfolder? Something has gone wrong with your install. Probably worth removing and reinstalling.